# How many 7 letter passwords can I make using letter A,B,C?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I did it using the multichoose formula but it does not work where Order Matters.
So I am stuck please help!!

EDIT: You have to use all three letters.

Comment: I'd just like to note that this is the same problem as that of [The Hunters and the Rabbits](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610250/a-question-on-probability-hunter-and-rabbit).

Answer (score 2):

There are three choices for the first letter, three choices for the second, and so on, for a total of $3 \times 3 \times ... \times 3 = 3^7$ possibilities.

---

With the additional restriction that we must use all three letters, note that there are exactly $2^7$ passwords which use only A and B. Likewise, there are $2^7$ passwords only using A and C, and $2^7$ only using B and C, for a total of $3 \cdot 2^7$ passwords which we must exclude. These sets overlap, since they double count passwords that only involve a single character - in particular, it counts the three single-character passwords twice.

Hence the total would be $3^7 - 3\cdot 2^7 + 3$.

Comment: Did you see the edit?

Comment: @ParthThakkar No, I answered before the edit was made.